# Type-safe rectangular multidimensional array type

Tags: arrays, scala, collections, types, multidimensional-array

How do you represent a **rectangular** 2-dimensional (or multidimensional) array data structure in Scala?

That is, each row has the same length, **verified at compile time**, but the dimensions are determined at runtime?

`Seq[Seq[A]]` has the desired interface, but it permits the user to provide a "ragged" array, which can result in a run-time failure.

`Seq[(A, A, A, A, A, A)]` (and similar) does verify that the lengths are the same, but it also forces this length to be specified at compile time.

#### Example interface

Here's an example interface of what I mean (of course, the inner dimension doesn't have to be tuples; it could be specified as lists or some other type):

```
// Function that takes a rectangular array
def processArray(arr : RectArray2D[Int]) = {
    // do something that assumes all rows of RectArray are the same length
}

// Calling the function (OK)
println(processArray(RectArray2D(
    ( 0,  1,  2,  3),
    (10, 11, 12, 13),
    (20, 21, 22, 23)
)))
// Compile-time error
println(processArray(RectArray2D(
    ( 0,  1,  2,  3),
    (10, 11, 12),
    (20, 21, 22, 23, 24)
)))
```

Comment: Can you please add a code sample of the desired interface and where compiler errors would be raised?

Comment: thanks, I added my own answer for your use-case.

Comment: By the way, your example is flawed. What you call 'valid' is a 4x3 rectangle, not a square.

Comment: It doesn't have to be square.

Comment: Wow, I totally read the entire question the wrong way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible using the [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library's sized types:

```
import shapeless._

def foo[A, N <: Nat](rect: Seq[Sized[Seq[A], N]]) = rect

val a = Seq(Sized(1, 2, 3), Sized(4, 5, 6))
val b = Seq(Sized(1, 2, 3), Sized(4, 5))
```

Now `foo(a)` compiles, but `foo(b)` doesn't.

This allows us to write something very close to your desired interface:

```
case class RectArray2D[A, N <: Nat](rows: Sized[Seq[A], N]*)

def processArray(arr: RectArray2D[Int, _]) = {
  // Run-time confirmation of what we've verified at compile-time.
  require(arr.rows.map(_.size).distinct.size == 1)
  // Do something.
}

// Compiles and runs.
processArray(RectArray2D(
  Sized( 0,  1,  2,  3),
  Sized(10, 11, 12, 13),
  Sized(20, 21, 22, 23)
))

// Doesn't compile.
processArray(RectArray2D(
  Sized( 0,  1,  2,  3),
  Sized(10, 11, 12),
  Sized(20, 21, 22, 23)
))
```

Comment: This may be what the author was looking for however the length is being specified at compile time as well in this solution. It would be even more impressive to find a solution that derived a length to use from io and then constructed the array.

Comment: But `foo` in this version is generic over the length, unlike the `Seq[(A, A, A)]` approach. I guess I don't understand how you could have both compile-time safety and a length you got from IO.

Comment: @Mechanical snail: With Travis Brown's comment in mind, you might be better of creating a matrix class that internally uses a ``Seq[Seq[A]]``, and that uses encapsulation to ensure that the user cannot violate the invariants of the internal representation.

Comment: That's along the lines that I was thinking. You can't use the type system to verify something that is specified at runtime. Encapsulation is the way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

Using encapsulation to ensure proper size.

```
final class Matrix[T]( cols: Int, rows: Int ) {
  private val container: Array[Array[T]] = Array.ofDim[T]( cols, rows )
  def get( col: Int, row: Int ) = container(col)(row)
  def set( col: Int, row: Int )( value: T ) { container(col)(row) = value } 
}
```

Comment: But presumably the author knows about encapsulation. It's probably the better solution for most real problems, but it's not the same as being able to verify at compile time that a collection some client is giving you has certain properties, which is what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** I misread the question, mistaking a rectangle for a square. Oh, well, if you're looking for squares, this would fit. Otherwise, you should go with @Travis Brown's answer.

This solution may not be the most generic one, but it coincides with the way *Tuple* classes are defined in Scala.

```
class Rect[T] private (val data: Seq[T])

object Rect {
    def apply[T](a1: (T, T), a2: (T, T)) = new Rect(Seq(a1, a2))
    def apply[T](a1: (T, T, T), a2: (T, T, T), a3: (T, T, T)) = new Rect(Seq(a1, a2, a3))
    // Continued...
}

Rect(
     (1, 2, 3),
     (3, 4, 5),
     (5, 6, 7))
```

This is the interface you were looking for and the compiler will stop you if you have invalid-sized rows, columns or type of element.