# Existential types and type members

Tags: scala, generics, types, existential-type, type-members

### What works (Part A)

Suppose I have a trait with a type parameter:

```
trait A[T]
```

I can use an existential type to write a method that will take a collection of `A`s that all have the same `T`:

```
def foo(as: Seq[A[X]] forSome { type X }) = true
```

Note that this is different from the following:

```
def otherFoo(as: Seq[A[X] forSome { type X }]) = true
```

Or the equivalent:

```
def otherFoo(as: Seq[A[_]]) = true
```

In these cases the scope of the existential is inside the `Seq`, so the `A`s can have different `T`s. With my original `foo` (with the existential scoping over the `Seq`), the following is fine:

```
foo(Seq(new A[Int] {}, new A[Int] {}))
```

But make the type parameters different and it doesn't compile:

```
scala> foo(Seq(new A[Int] {}, new A[String] {}))
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[A[_ >: java.lang.String with Int]]
 required: Seq[A[X]] forSome { type X }

              foo(Seq(new A[Int] {}, new A[String] {}))
                     ^
```

This is all pretty straightforward.

### What works (Part B)

Now suppose I have a similar trait with a type member instead of a type parameter:

```
trait B { type T }
```

I can write a method that will only take a `B` with some specified `T`:

```
scala> def bar[X](b: B { type T = X }) = true
bar: [X](b: B{type T = X})Boolean

scala> bar[Int](new B { type T = Int })
res5: Boolean = true

scala> bar[String](new B { type T = Int })
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.Object with B
 required: B{type T = String}
              bar[String](new B { type T = Int })
                          ^
```

Again, this works exactly the way you'd expect it to.

### What doesn't work

When we try to write the equivalent of our `foo` above, but for type members, things get weird.

```
scala> def baz(bs: Seq[B { type T = X }] forSome { type X }) = true
baz: (as: Seq[B{type T = X}] forSome { type X })Boolean

scala> baz(Seq(new B { type T = Int }, new B { type T = String }))
res7: Boolean = true
```

That the last line compiles makes no sense to me. I've told it that I want all the type members to be the same. My `foo` shows that I can do this for type parameters, and `bar` shows that I can constrain a type based on its type members. But I can't combine the two.

I've tried this on 2.9.2 and 2.10.0-M5.

### Motivation

This question is inspired by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12046974/334519), where my first thought was, oh, just use an existential type (setting aside for a second the issue that [it seems to be impossible to get an existential type to scope of the type of a repeated parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11540687/334519), which would be handy here):

```
def accept(rs: Seq[RList[Int] { type S = X }] forSome { type X }) = true
```

But this doesn't actually work—you get the same weird result as in the simplified example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally sort it out (at least I hope so). Let's do it the other way. We build our trait:

```
scala> trait B {type T}
defined trait B
```

We try and build a sequence of `B`:

```
scala> Seq(new B {type T = Int}, new B {type T = String})
res0: Seq[B{type T >: String with Int}] = List($anon$1@592b12d, $anon$2@61ae0436)
```

Damn, it works! Ok, we don't have an equality for `type T` but let's play with it:

```
scala> res0 : (Seq[B {type T = X}] forSome {type X >: String with Int})
res1: Seq[B{type T = X}] forSome { type X >: String with Int } = List($anon$1@592b12d, $anon$2@61ae0436)
```

It's closer. No wait, it's not closer, It's **better** than what you've proposed as a parameter of `baz`, we do not only provide a raw type, we also have a upper bound! Thus, we can clearly pass it to `baz`. This is why it doesn't work as you expected.

Comment: Thanks—I think this gets me closer to understanding what's going on here. I'm still not sure I grasp why this works but the type parameter equivalent doesn't.

Comment: You mean, the part A of your question? It doesn't work because type parameters are invariant. If you try the same with `trait A[+T]` you're gonna get the same result.

Answer (score -1):

In your example :

```
scala> def baz(bs: Seq[B { type T = X }] forSome { type X }) = true
```

tells compiler that the function baz takes a Seq of the trait B's. The trait B happens to take a type member T but as far as compiler is concerned, it's totally fine for the function baz to take a Seq of the trait B's even if the types of the B's type member T are not the same. If you want the function to baz to take a Seq of the trait B with the same type members, you need to tell the compiler as the following:

```
scala> def baz[X](bs: Seq[B { type T = X }]) = true
baz: [X](bs: Seq[B{type T = X}])Boolean


scala> baz[Int](Seq(new B { type T = Int }, new B { type T = String }))
    <console>:10: error: type mismatch;
    found   : java.lang.Object with B
    required: B{type T = Int}
              baz[Int](Seq(new B { type T = Int }, new B { type T = String }))
                                               ^

scala> baz[Int](Seq(new B { type T = Int }, new B { type T = Int }))
res10: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Right—I understand that this is what the compiler does, but why? It seems inconsistent, for the reasons I outlined in the question. And sometimes you don't care about `X` (apart from knowing that it's the same) and it would be nice to have the types reflect that.